# Difference between `Function` and `(...args: any[]) => any`

Tags: typescript, types

What is the difference between `Function` and `(...args: any[]) => any`?

Interestingly, I just noticed that `Function` is not assignable to `(...args: any[]) => any`, but why?

```
    declare let foo: Function;
    declare let bar: (...args: any[]) => any;
    bar = foo;
//  ~~~
//  ^^^
//  Type 'Function' is not assignable to type '(...args: any[]) => any'.
//    Type 'Function' provides no match for the signature '(...args: any[]): any'. (2322)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEEQBd4DMD2GBc8BiArgHZjICWGRA3AFCiSwJKoBGsuAFAHQ+wDmAZ1xQiATwDaAXQCU8ALwA+eCNG02Meeiy0gA)

Comment: You're right. I just tried it out now in the playground and indeed: it let me use a `=> never` function in a `=> any`-typed variable. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: Ok, I deleted my comments too then. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently the [`Function`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/868638ae04e7eab800db7213530f1ab61a71e815/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L272-L304) interface doesn't have a callable signature in its declaration.  Although if you have an object of type `Function`, you're allowed to call it *if* it were of type `(...args: any) => any`.  There is a (somewhat old) open issue, [microsoft/TypeScript#20007](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20007), asking for this to be changed.  There's a comment there which [says](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20007#issuecomment-405766256):

> The original intention of `Function` is to not be callable. in other words, `Function` to function types should be like `unknown` to other types, but not callable. we have since relaxed this restriction giving `Function` a callable behavior in the compiler through special casing. We have talked about making this a `--noImplicitAny` error since, it is really unsafe to call `Function`s.

If you really care about this situation, you might want to go to that issue and give it your  and possibly describe your use case.  Pragmatically speaking, though, it's unlikely to be changed, so you're probably better off just noting the weird discrepancy and moving on.